# mysqltuner.pl shows [!!] 2 different collations for database

Tags: mariadb, collation, mariadb-10.1, mysqltuner

`mysqltuner.pl` shows me result

```
[!!] 2 different collations for database ccdb
```

I don't see two different `COLLATE` on DB level. Is this even possible? How to verify?

```
> show create database ccdb;
+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Database | Create Database                                                                       |
+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ccdb     | CREATE DATABASE `ccdb` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci */ |
+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

> select * from information_schema.schemata where schema_name = 'ccdb';
+--------------+-------------+----------------------------+------------------------+----------+
| CATALOG_NAME | SCHEMA_NAME | DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME | DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME | SQL_PATH |
+--------------+-------------+----------------------------+------------------------+----------+
| def          | ccdb        | utf8                       | utf8_unicode_ci        | NULL     |
+--------------+-------------+----------------------------+------------------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I see different `TABLE_COLLATION`. Is this a problem?

```
> SELECT count(*), TABLE_COLLATION FROM information_schema.TABLES  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='ccdb' group by TABLE_COLLATION;
+----------+-----------------+
| count(*) | TABLE_COLLATION |
+----------+-----------------+
|       29 | utf8_bin        |
|       26 | utf8_general_ci |
+----------+-----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

> select version();
+-----------------+
| version()       |
+-----------------+
| 10.1.20-MariaDB |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not a problem. The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-table.html) sums things up.

> Every table has a table character set and a table collation. The
>   CREATE TABLE and ALTER TABLE statements have optional clauses for
>   specifying the table character set and collation

The default database character set/collation values are used for a table if the relevant clauses are not specified at table creation time.